# how to change the background of an iphone app when it launches?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background-image

Everything is in the title but I have to make myself clear :

**I don't mean** : how to automatically change the background of the app once it has finished launching.

**What I mean is** : when you first launch the app, before the first view is loaded by the iphone there is a black screen. Is it possible to change this black screen which I get when waiting for the first view to appear? I'd like to put a picture instead.

Thanks!
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a Default.png and a Default@2x.png (for retina) and all the work is done for you. Or if you have payed to be a developer, download xcode 4 gm, and you can double click on the loading screen area and you can have it named what ever you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a picture called "Default.png" to the project (size of the iPhone screen) and it'll automatically appear.

Comment: @John If it works great you should accept his answer. See the white checkmark below the voting buttons on the left of the answer? Click it.

Comment: @fluchpunkt Thanks for the tip, I didn't know it!

Answer (score 1):

You can add Default.png and it's variations to your project. This image will be displayed as splash screen during application startup (before the first view is loaded).

Search for Application Launch Images at ...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html

Answer (score 1):

You must specify Launch image
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW9

Answer (score 1):

The docs here explain the different types of launch images can should use:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12